# "As though he thought he were" or "as though he had thought he was"

Tags: tense

I have a question about the phrase "as though" and an unreal situation.

When you are describing someone who liked giving orders to everyone, which sentence can you use?

> He acted as though he thought he **were** our boss.
>
> He acted as though he **had thought** he was our boss.

The unreal situation is that he thought he was our boss. As the bossy person wasn't our boss and wouldn't have thought he was actually our boss, I think subjunctive is necessary in this sentence. But I don't know which verb should change tense for the subjunctive, thought/had thought or was/were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main unreal situation is that ***he is not our boss***. I would write your sentence as:

> He acted ***as though he were*** our boss.

***Had been*** is not recommended in this case, as *acted* is simultaneous with the unreality of *were*.

If however, you want to emphasise that he acted like a boss, but ***not because he thought he was the boss***, this situation is peculiar, but let's say it can exist. Then you could either say:

> He acted as though he thought he was our boss. (one irrealis - *thought* - is enough)

or

> Although he did not think he was the boss, he acted as though he did.